# Sendgrid mails not sent from crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, cron

I am working on an RoR app.

I am trying to run a shell script from crontab on the app server. The shell script invokes a rake task which is supposed to deliver a mail. The script runs fine and sends out a mail when run from console, but fails when run via crontab.

I get the following error when running the script in crontab:

```
rake aborted!
550 Cannot receive from specified address <help@voylla.com>: Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

Could someone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the "unathenticated senders not allowed" error, that means your mail server or program is not attempting the AUTH LOGIN command during the SMTP connection.

`Unauthenticated senders not allowed` means your providing either a `bad username or password`.
The easiest way to resolve this is to reset your password:

https://sendgrid.com/user/forgotPassword

Please check your `username` and `password` on  `config.action_mailer.smtp_setting` or `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` setting

For more information please check

http://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/unauthenticated_senders_not_allowed

in development.rb please also check

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Comment: I am providing correct username and password, coz the same is working on the staging server. How can I invoke `AUTH LOGIN`?

Comment: please check out my updated post to check `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp` in your environment file